# What was the process by which the modern border control system developed?

Tags: law, international-relations, government

I know that today, if I take a cruise of the Mediterranean, then each time the boat stops in a new country, and I wish to go ashore and see the sites, that I will need to have appropriate documentation.  At some location near the docks, I will be greeted by a uniformed agent of the host nation, who will inspect my passport, ensure the proper visas exist if required, and possibly search any day-pack I am carrying.  I am interested in learning the history of this concept, at least from the last few hundred years.

These questions [How did modern border crossing security develop?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/23053/15118) and [When did passports become common](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/17190/when-passports-border-checks-became-widespread) contain some very helpful information.  I'm looking for a more detailed timeline of the development of border controls.  The answer to the first question, " "passports were not generally required for international travel until the first world war" (quoted from the Guardian) is a useful top level summary, but history is more complicated - for example, passports are mentioned in "Around the world in 80 days" (1873).  What changed between 1873 and 1914?

I'm looking not to identify a year or event when border controls existed, but to understand the process by which the modern border control system came into place.

Comment: Except for the very wealth, who have always been welcome, *casual tourism* is a late 19th century phenomenon. Guilds ran the mechanism of immigration control, for all intents and purposes, until sometime in the 17th century or so (in Europe at least).

Comment: One might consider the pilgrimage a sort of tourism...

Comment: @without any doubt, it IS a sort tourism. Travel for some sort of experience. Piligrimage even has its souvenirs.

Comment: Great Wall of China comes to mind.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace  Great edit!  Much thanks.  (To everyone else- re-open please?)